# How to configure project in Eclipse so that jsps can be validated properly including <%@page import="...%>in <@include file="...">

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, liferay, liferay-ide

Let there be a (Liferay hook plugin) eclipse project xyz-hook.
And let there be the file a.jsp

```
<% @include file="/html/portal/init.jsp" %>
<% InitImportedClass.yxz(); %>
```

and let there be the included init.jsp in another (referenced) project.

```
<% @page import="de.company.InitImportedClass" %>
```

For a.jsp in project xyz-hook we get a warning in line 1

`Fragment "/html/portal/init.jsp" was not found at expected path /xyz-hook/src/main/webapp/html/portal/init.jsp`

and an error in line 2

`InitImportedClass cannot be resolved`

Is there any way to tell Eclipse to go looking for init.jsp in the other project?

The project (Liferay portal trunk) containing the init.jsp is already referenced.
I also created an synthetic jar containing the jsp as well, added it to the local maven repository and as dependency to project xyz-hook.

PS: For those wondering, this is a typical setup for Liferay hooks when replacing jsps, that are provided by the portal core.

PPS: I'm aware that I could deactivated jsp validation altogether, but that is something I'd like to avoid, since otherwise imports that are really missing won't be shown as error either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd very much welcome such a feature, but according to my last conversations about it, it will be *really* hard to solve and requires major changes in quite a few components. Given that the jsp editor is somewhat fragile already (sometimes it's showing validation errors that are not there) I don't see anybody attacking it in the near future. But I'll take this as a cause to nag again. (You might want to post a feature requests on https://issues.liferay.com/browse/IDE or find an existing one and support it)

However, there are some workarounds:

With the `<liferay-util:include />` jsp-tag you can specify a servletContext and include another JSP from your own hook. This will run in the specified webapp's classloader and eclipse can handle that one well. In your jsp-hook you still need to deactivate jsp validation, but the remaining JSP is just a few characters doing the include business, and that's quite ok.

You'll have a bit more work getting all the context etc., but if you are doing some heavier work, this might be an option. You can also use custom classes from a hook - which you typically can't when you introduce a new jsp into the portal classloader.

*Pseudocode* example:

In your hook, overriding jsps from the portal, e.g. in `my-hook/custom-jsps/html/portlet/navigation/view.jsp`

```
   <%-- omitted taglib includes --%>
   <liferay-util:include 
         page="/jsp/navigation/view.jsp" 
         servletContext="<%=this.getServletContext().getContext("/my-hook")%>" />
```

this will override Liferay's default jsp for the navigation portlet with your own implementation. However, it obviously doesn't do much, but includes `/jsp/navigation/view.jsp` which it will find within your own hook (note: `/custom-jsps` contains the jsps that override the portal's - files in `/jsp` will be served within the hook's context:

in `my-hook/jsp/navigation/view.jsp`

```
   <%-- omitted taglib includes --%> 
   <ul>
   <li>build</li><li>your</li><li>navigation</li>
   </ul>
   <!-- you also have access to classes introduced by your hook -->
   <%=CustomClassInHook.doSomething() %>
```

The drawback is that you'll have to "repeat" the initialization that every Liferay jsp typically gets on your own - e.g. import statements, make themeDisplay available etc.

Also, be aware: Above is pseudocode. I've just typed it here from some (pen&paper) notes, not ran it. So it might require a bit more work and have other drawbacks or shortcomings.

---

Another possibility is to develop complex overridden jsps within Liferay's sourcecode and - when done - carry them over into your own hook. You'll get a build-time hit if you need to rebuild Liferay (but who rebuilds for a jsp change?) but you get all the IDE luxury

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply - I will evaluate those suggestions at Monday and give feedback.

Comment: I read and reread your first recommendation, but i really don't get it - would you mind to add a minimal example of what you describe?

Comment: added pseudocode. If it's almost correct but requires a few tweaks, feel free to correct, so that there's some public reference to come to later.

Comment: Okay, now I understand the concept. Thanks for the additional explanation!